# Wagtail Preview - request session does not have session_key

Tags: django, wagtail

Wagtail Preview - request session does not have session_key

When we edit some sub pages the preview shows validation errors exist

this wagtail code is not retrieving the data

```
def _get_data_from_session(self):
        post_data, _ = self.request.session.get(self.session_key, (None, None))
        if not isinstance(post_data, str):
            post_data = ""
        return QueryDict(post_data
```

as the request.session does not contain the session_key 'wagtail-preview-nnn' it does contain
the key for another page

Answer (score 0):

we found the answer for this, we were using signed cookies for the session engine
Wagtail stores the preview data in the session, cookies have a size limitation and the preview content was greater than this
we have changed to using Redis backed sessions